# verify_captcha validation: If a user fails to login twice using cookies coding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, recaptcha

This is the functionality i used for "when a user fails to attempt login twice r thrice".

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]

prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create

prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

def new

cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts] || 0

if params[:user] && cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email] 

    cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1

  else

    cookies[:login_attempts] = 0

  end

end

self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)

clean_up_passwords(resource)

respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))

end

# POST /resource/sign_in

def create

cookies[:email] =   params[:user][:email]

self.resource =  warden.authenticate!(auth_options)

if cookies[:email]

  cookies[:login_attempts] = 0

  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?

  sign_in(resource_name, resource)

  respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

else

  unless params[:user][:email].blank?

    if   cookies[:email].eql?(params[:user][:email])

      cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1

    else

      cookies[:login_attempts] = 0

    end

  end

  render :new

end

end end
```

In sessions/new:

```
   <% if cookies[:login_attempts].to_i >= 3 %>
                  <div><%= raw recaptcha_tags %></div>
              <% end %>
```

I am able to show captcha successfully but where to add "if verify_captcha" validation for the above controller. Its quite confusing. 
Please try to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented this same logic in one of my projects with the following controller:

```
class Devs::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  prepend_before_filter :captcha_valid, :only => [:create]
  layout 'devise'

  def new
    cookies[:login_attempts] ||= 0
    cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
  end

  def captcha_valid
    if cookies[:login_attempts] && cookies[:login_attempts].to_i > 3
      if verify_recaptcha
        true
      else
        build_resource
        respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

It's indeed a bit confusing but we don't need the recaptcha to be checked in the "new" action, this action is used only to show the login page. We need to check the recaptcha only in the "creation" action which is, in fact, where the session will be created. Therefore, we have the line `prepend_before_filter :captcha_valid, :only => [:create]` that will call the method `captcha_valid` and make the necessaries verifications.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I just added the captcha_valid method for my above code, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

#### This works fine for me:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  prepend_before_action :recaptcha, only: [:create]

  def recaptcha    
    if not verify_recaptcha
      redirect_to "/users/sign_in"
      return false
    end    
  end

  def create
    # custom sign-in code
  end

end
```